# Divs with the same width are not the same width

Tags: css

I set the width of two separate divs (circle_bg_l and circle_bg_r) both to 7vh, however one of them appears to be bigger. Here is the code:

```css
    @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
margin-top: 0;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
background-image: url(html-bg2.png);
background-size: 0.5%;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-color: #111111;
overflow: auto;
}

#headbar_left {
position: fixed;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
width: 51vw;
height: 10vh;
background-color: #161616;
border-bottom: 1vh solid #8704ff;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transform-origin: 100% -50%;
-o-transform-origin: 100% -50%;
-moz-transform-origin: 100% -50%;
-webkit-transform-origin: 100% -50%;
-ms-transform-origin: 100% -50%;
}

#headbar_right {
position: fixed;
right: 0;
margin: 0;
width: 51vw;
height: 10vh;
background-color: #161616;
border-bottom: 1vh solid #8704ff;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transform-origin: 0% 50%;
-o-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
-moz-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
-webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
-ms-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}

#circle_bg_l {
position: fixed;
z-index: 0;
width: 7vh;
height: 10vh;
left: calc(50vw - 7vh);
transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
background-color: Transparent;
box-sizing: border-box;
-o-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
}

#circle_bg_r {
position: fixed;
z-index: 0;
width: 7vh;
height: 10vh;
right: calc(50vw - 7vh);
transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
background-color: Transparent;
box-sizing: border-box;
-o-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.show {
background-color: #8704ff !important;
}

#circle_logo {
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
width: 14vh;
height: 14vh;
border-radius: 7vh;
background-color: #161616;
left: calc(50vw - 7vh);
box-sizing: border-box;
-o-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
border: 1vh solid #8704ff;
text-align: center;
line-height: 14vh;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
background-image: url(html-logo.png);
background-size: 100%;
}

.l_menu {
height: 10vh;
z-index: 2;
line-height: 10vh;
vertical-align: center;
text-align: center;
color: white;
font-family: "Impact";
font-size: 2.5vh;
transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
width: calc((50vw - 7vh) / 3);
float: left;
}

.l_menu:hover {
color: #161616;
background-color: #8704ff;
}

.r_menu {
height: 10vh;
z-index: 2;
line-height: 10vh;
vertical-align: center;
text-align: center;
color: white;
font-family: "Impact";
font-size: 2.5vh;
transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
width: calc((50vw - 7vh) / 3);
float: right;
}

.r_menu:hover {
color: #161616;
background-color: #8704ff;
}

.spin {
transform: rotate(360deg);
-o-transform: rotate(360deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.collapse {
transform: scaleX(0);
-o-transform: scaleX(0);
-moz-transform: scaleX(0);
-webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
-ms-transform: scaleX(0);
}

.move_left {
transform: translateX(calc(7vh - 50vw));
-o-transform: translateX(calc(7vh - 50vw));
-moz-transform: translateX(calc(7vh - 50vw));
-webkit-transform: translateX(calc(7vh - 50vw));
-ms-transform: translateX(calc(7vh - 50vw));

}

.move_fast {
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out !important;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out !important;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out !important;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out !important;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out !important;
}

#circle_logo:hover {
transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out !important;
-o-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out !important;
-moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out !important;
-webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out !important;
-ms-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out !important;
border-radius: 0;
}

#body_content {
position: absolute;
width: calc(100vw - 28vh);
height: 105vh;
margin-right: 14vh;
margin-left: 14vh;
background-color: #161616;
z-index: -1;
box-shadow: 0 3vh 10vh 4vh black;
color: white;
font-family: "Impact";
font-size: 10vh;
padding-top: 21vh;
}

#t_s {
font-size: 2vh;
}
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="uh.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>uh</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="headbar_left">
<div class="l_menu">FIRST</div>
<div class="l_menu">SECOND</div>
<div id="l_mid" class="l_menu">THIRD</div>
</div>
<div id="headbar_right">
<div class="r_menu">SIXTH</div>
<div class="r_menu">FIFTH</div>
<div id="r_mid" class="r_menu">FOURTH</div>
</div>
<div id="circle_bg_l"></div><a href="uh.html"><div id="circle_logo"></div></a><div id="circle_bg_r"></div>
<div id="body_content"><center>WHAT IS THIS PAGE?<p id="t_s">no one knows</center></div>
</body>
<script>
var a = 1;

function remove() {
 if (a === 0) {
  $("#circle_logo").removeClass('move_left');
  setTimeout(function() {
   $("#circle_logo").removeClass('move_fast');
   $("#circle_logo").removeClass('spin');
         $("#headbar_left, #headbar_right").removeClass('collapse');
         $("#circle_logo").css("background-image", "url(html-logo.png)");
         $("a").attr("href", "uh.html");
        }, 300);
        a = 1;
    }
}

function add() {
 if (a === 1) {
  $("#circle_logo").addClass('spin');
     $("#headbar_left, #headbar_right").addClass('collapse');
     setTimeout(function() {
      $("#circle_logo").addClass('move_left');
      $("#circle_logo").addClass('move_fast');
         $("#circle_logo").css("background-image", "url(up-arrow.png)");
         $("a").attr("href", "#top");
     }, 400);
     a = 0;
    }
}

$(document).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
        add();
    }
    else {
        remove();
    }
});

$("#l_mid").mouseover(function() {
$("#circle_bg_l").addClass("show");
});

$("#l_mid").mouseout(function() {
$("#circle_bg_l").removeClass("show");
});

$("#r_mid").mouseover(function() {
$("#circle_bg_r").addClass("show");
});

$("#r_mid").mouseout(function() {
$("#circle_bg_r").removeClass("show");
});
</script>
</html>
```

I also just noticed after running the snippet that the divs do not line up the same way they do when I open the webpage in a browser. Any idea how to fix these problems? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same size in firefox, chrome and safari (latest versions on OS X) - according to the snippet you posted. They also appear to my eyes the same size.

That said, your browser or device might be showing some differences, one possibility is your use of VW. You have 2 header portions, each using 51VW next to each other. That's roughly the equivalent of having 2 sections use 51% of the width, and not add to 100vw. 
I would try changing those to 50VW each and test again.

Comment: Thanks, I tried what you suggested, but unfortunately it didn't work. I'm testing the website using Firefox on Windows 8, but it might be a really old version - I don't know if that would affect it.